# Sort an array of objects with 6 conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, methods

I am super stuck with sorting my array of objects.

```
const users = useMemo(() => [userDetails, ...otherParticipants]
        .sort((a, b) => b.isTyping - a.isTyping)
        .sort((a, b) => b.liveDetails.status - a.liveDetails.status)
        .sort((a, b) => b.hasRaisedHand - a.hasRaisedHand)
        .sort((a, b) => b.isOnline - a.isOnline)     
, [userDetails, otherParticipants])
```

I tried chaining sorts and it worked a bit. Then I tried conditional, but nothing seemed to work with all that I needed to sort. I would really appreciate some guidance. Sorry for the long post...

```
[
        {
        
           isOnline: true,
           hasRaisedHand: false,
           isTyping: false,
           liveDetails: {
              status: 'pending',
              camera: false,
              mic: false,
           },
        },
          {
        
           isOnline: true,
           hasRaisedHand: false,
           isTyping: false,
           liveDetails: {
              status: 'active',
              camera: false,
              mic: false,
           },
        },
    {
        
           isOnline: false,
           hasRaisedHand: false,
           isTyping: false,
           liveDetails: {
              status: 'disabled',
              camera: false,
              mic: false,
           },
        },
    {
        
           isOnline: true,
           hasRaisedHand: false,
           isTyping: true,
           liveDetails: {
              status: 'disabled',
              camera: false,
              mic: false,
           },
        },

    {
        
           isOnline: true,
           hasRaisedHand: true,
           isTyping: false,
           liveDetails: {
              status: 'disabled',
              camera: false,
              mic: false,
           },
        },
]
```

This is the order I need the objects sorted into:

```
isTyping: true
status: 'active'
status: 'pending'
hasRaisedHand: true
isOnline: true
isOnline: false
```

example: an object that has the key `isTyping: true` should be in front of the object that has a `status: 'pending'`.

example 2: if an object has `status: 'pending'` but also has `isTyping: true`, it should be in the front of the array.

this is the order the objects need to sort into, but I cant seem to get it to work at all.

This would be the order I need:

```
    [
                
                  
            
            {
                
                   isOnline: true,
                   hasRaisedHand: false,
                   **isTyping: true,**
                   liveDetails: {
                      status: 'disabled',
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
    {
                
                   isOnline: true,
                   hasRaisedHand: false,
                   isTyping: false,
                   liveDetails: {
                      **status: 'active',**
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
    {
                
                   isOnline: true,
                   hasRaisedHand: false,
                   isTyping: false,
                   liveDetails: {
                      **status: 'pending',**
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
        
            {
                
                   isOnline: true,
                   **hasRaisedHand: true**,
                   isTyping: false,
                   liveDetails: {
                      status: 'disabled',
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
{
                
                   **isOnline: true,**
                   hasRaisedHand: false,
                   isTyping: false,
                   liveDetails: {
                      status: 'disabled',
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
    {
                
                   **isOnline: false,**
                   hasRaisedHand: false,
                   isTyping: false,
                   liveDetails: {
                      status: 'disabled',
                      camera: false,
                      mic: false,
                   },
                },
        ]
```

Comment: what means `liveStatusTypes.disabled`?

Comment: Hi I edited my post to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain the conditions **inside** of `sort` by using an object for sorting various states.

```js
const
    data = [{ isOnline: true, hasRaisedHand: false, isTyping: false, liveDetails: { status: 'pending', camera: false, mic: false } }, { isOnline: true, hasRaisedHand: false, isTyping: false, liveDetails: { status: 'active', camera: false, mic: false } }, { isOnline: false, hasRaisedHand: false, isTyping: false, liveDetails: { status: 'disabled', camera: false, mic: false } }, { isOnline: true, hasRaisedHand: false, isTyping: true, liveDetails: { status: 'disabled', camera: false, mic: false } }, { isOnline: true, hasRaisedHand: true, isTyping: false, liveDetails: { status: 'disabled', camera: false, mic: false } }],
    status = { active: 1, pending: 2, disabled: 3 };

data.sort((a, b) =>
    b.isTyping - a.isTyping ||
    status[a.liveDetails.status] - status[b.liveDetails.status] ||
    b.hasRaisedHand - a.hasRaisedHand ||
    b.isOnline - a.isOnline
);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code where we sort the data based on a sorting score of elements as per your requirements. Notice that they have a priority based sore i.e., higher the sorting priority criteria, higher the score. The gap between each sorting criteria is kept far apart so that conditions don't overlap. If conditions increase so will we change the score type increments. Check this:

```
function getScore(a) {
  var n = a.isTyping ? 30 : 0;
  n += a.liveDetails.status == 'active' ? 15 : 0;
  n += a.liveDetails.status == 'pending' ? 14 : 0;
  n += a.hasRaisedHand ? 8 : 0;
  n += a.isOnline ? 2 : 0;
  return n;
}

var results = data.sort((a, b) => getScore(a) < getScore(b));
 
console.log(results);
```